# Mysql select from multiple tables based on like count

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have this problem with my sql statement and am not sure how to get around it.
I am using WordPress and the WTI Like Post plugin
Here is the query:

```
 SELECT wpblog_posts.ID, wpblog_posts.post_title, wpblog_posts.post_excerpt, wpblog_posts.guid, wpblog_posts.post_author, wpblog_wti_like_post.value, wpblog_wti_like_post.post_id 
 FROM wpblog_posts, wpblog_wti_like_post 
 LEFT JOIN wpblog_term_relationships rel ON rel.object_id = wpblog_posts.ID 
 LEFT JOIN wpblog_term_taxonomy tax ON tax.term_taxonomy_id = rel.term_taxonomy_id 
 LEFT JOIN wpblog_terms t ON t.term_id = tax.term_id WHERE t.term_id = 165 
 AND wpblog_posts.post_type = 'post' 
 AND wpblog_wti_like_post.post_id = wpblog_posts.ID 
 ORDER BY wpblog_wti_like_post.value 
 LIMIT 20
```

Here is a screen shot of the wpblog_wti_like_post table:
[image]

So what i'm trying to do is select all posts from a category, and order those posts by `wpblog_wti_like_post.value`
Now in the category some posts are liked and disliked, and appear in the table `wpblog_wti_like_post`
but some posts don't appear in that table.

How would I:

a. Select all posts in that category

b. Order by wpblog_wti_like_post.value

I am completely stumped on how to accomplish this.

Cheers

UPDATE

This query selects all posts from a specific category and works fine, but the query above doesn't:

```
SELECT wpblog_posts.ID, wpblog_posts.post_title, wpblog_posts.post_excerpt, wpblog_posts.guid, wpblog_posts.post_author 
FROM wpblog_posts 
LEFT JOIN wpblog_term_relationships rel ON rel.object_id = wpblog_posts.ID 
LEFT JOIN wpblog_term_taxonomy tax ON tax.term_taxonomy_id = rel.term_taxonomy_id 
LEFT JOIN wpblog_terms t ON t.term_id = tax.term_id 
WHERE t.term_id = 165 
LIMIT 20
```

Comment: Could it be the `LIMIT` statement in the query?? You are only getting the first 20 results

Comment: Hi, No it's not the limit, as no results are returned. Confirmed as I removed the limit.

The query works when I remove anything which references the table `wpblog_wti_like_post` Cheers

Comment: What do you exactly mean with `category`? Which row is that referred?

Comment: I have updated my question, but category is which category the posts are in and refers to the row `term_id` in `wpblog_terms`. So some posts will be in one category and other posts will be in a different category. Cheers

Comment: As elaborated upon in my 'answer', your existing 'fine' query is faintly nonsensical. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: I dont know how I can explain this any clearer, one query works and one doesn't. I'm thinking there is no solution to this problem, but my knowledge of wordpress and mysql is still limited.

Comment: I believe I've explained how in the linked answer.

Answer (score 0):

Tip: something like the following is more readable...

```
SELECT p.ID
     , p.post_title
     , p.post_excerpt
     , p.guid
     , p.post_author
  FROM wpblog_posts p
  LEFT 
  JOIN wpblog_term_relationships rel 
    ON rel.object_id = p.ID
  LEFT 
  JOIN wpblog_term_taxonomy tax 
    ON tax.term_taxonomy_id = rel.term_taxonomy_id 
  LEFT 
  JOIN wpblog_terms t 
    ON t.term_id = tax.term_id
 WHERE t.term_id = 165
 LIMIT 20
```

Some observations on the above:

- `LEFT JOIN x... WHERE x =` is the same as `INNER JOIN x`
- There is no point LEFT JOINing tables from which you select no columns. As stated, the above is in fact an inner join, so this fact is for future reference only.
- LIMIT without ORDER BY is fairly meaningless

Comment: Thanks for the tip. But the left joins are required due to the way wordpress stores data. So to get all posts from a category, in this case `WHERE t.term_id = 165` the LEFT JOINS are required. Additionally the LIMIT does have meaning as it is used with infinite scroll and ajax. So I need to limit the number of results until the user scrolls down the page.

Comment: @webDevGuy 1. Try running EXPLAIN EXTENDED followed by SHOW WARNINGS. That's what MySQL 'sees' when executing the query. 2. Rows in SQL have no order, so without an ORDER BY clause, LIMIT returns an indetermine result.